# Expanding a &rest parameter in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Suppose I get tired of writing "format t ..." all the time, and want something a little fewer keystrokes.

So I write this:

```
(defun puts (fstring &rest vars)
  (format t fstring vars))

(puts "~a ~a" 1 2)

;; error message results, because vars became (1 2)
```

Now, `vars` has been transformed into a list of whatever params I passed in. It needs to be "expanded" out into a list of values.

What is the typical solution to do this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `apply` for that: `(apply #'format t fstring vars)` expands `vars` into separate arguments to `format`.

Comment: Thank you. I always run into this issue but I can never remember or figure out quite what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Besides `apply`, there also the possibility to do this with a macro in which you can use  `,@` to splice lists inside backquotes:

```
(defmacro puts (fstring &rest vars)
  `(format t ,fstring ,@vars))
```

Comment: I've done that too, but macros and I are not sufficiently comfortable yet. :-)

Comment: Functions are preferred, since they are easier to use.

Comment: @Rainer: I know that functions should be preferred if there's no specific requirement to use a macro, but in the context of this question's title (expanding &rest parameters) it seemed noteworthy to me that there's special support for this in backquotes.

Comment: örd: sure, Backquotes are just a different syntax over LIST and related functions and generally unrelated to macros. Your backquote expression does the same as (list* 'format t fstring vars). But if you have a macro, you can't APPLY PUTS. Etc. Macros are the wrong tool for that.